# Defining global variables in MobileFirst Platform Adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

Suppose I have a MobileFirst Adapter implementation like this;

```
var count = 0;
function doStuff() {

}
```

Is the `count` value the same throughout the MobileFirst server (and other client apps)? Or are they maintained per client (i.e safe to use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined in an adapter are not available in/shareable with other  adapters.

If you'd like to share this variable, what you can do is send the data to another adapter via an action called "adapter mashup". This is explained in the following tutorial: [Advanced adapter usage and mashup](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/). This is not ideal for all cases, so make sure it fits yours.

Comment: So it is safe to store client specific data. Thanks Idan Adar.